# Azure Mobile Apps: How to broadcast a cross platform message to Droid + iOS

Tags: c#, azure, azure-notificationhub

I know how to send targeted messages from the various tutorials with code like that:

```
// Get the current user SID and create a tag for the current user.
var claimsPrincipal = this.User as ClaimsPrincipal;
string sid = claimsPrincipal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
string userTag = "_UserId:" + sid;

// Build a dictionary for the template with the item message text.
var notification = new Dictionary { { "message", item.Text } };

// Send a template notification to the user ID.
await hub.SendTemplateNotificationAsync(notification, userTag);
```

But I struggle to figure out how to send to all my registered UserIds.

I hope there is some method like:

```
// Send a template notification to all UserIds
await hub.SendTemplateNotificationAsync(notification);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's an [overload of SendTemplateNotificationAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.notificationhubs.notificationhubclient?redirectedfrom=MSDN#Microsoft_Azure_NotificationHubs_NotificationHubClient_SendTemplateNotificationAsync_System_Collections_Generic_IDictionary_System_String_System_String__) that looks exactly as you described:

```
public Task<NotificationOutcome> SendTemplateNotificationAsync(
                                       IDictionary<string, string> properties)
```

Does it not work for you?

An alternative would be to register your users with an additional tag (e.g. "registered user" for all users or "paid user"/"trial user" if you need to slice them somehow) and then use the method you're currently using to send messages, but to this broader tag.

Comment: Thank you very much, that works. Its sometimes hard to find all related information in one place at the azure docs.